# Take an element from a list and assign it to a variable

Tags: python

How to take out an element from a list and assign it to a variable

For eg
The element `'one'`in the list

```
['one']
```

Should be taken out and assigned to the variable `element_1`

So that it would look like

```
element_1='one'
```

Comment: `lst = ['something'] x = lst[0]`

Comment: This is what the indexing operator is for. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_access.asp

Comment: If you want to remove it from the list at the same time as you assign it, use the `pop()` method.

Comment: What rules do you have for getting the value? Is it the first value in the list? Or are you specifically looking for the string "one" in the list? Should the value be removed from the list during assigment? Some basic list operations are in the standard python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists. This is such basic stuff that you are better off going to a tutorial/class than asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
mylist = ['one','two','three']
required = 'one' # You can change this

for i in mylist:
    if i == required:
        element_1 = i
```

Or even better you can use `.pop` method like -

```
element_1 = mylist.pop(0) # The index of the required element
```

Or just use index -

```
element_1 = mylist[0]
```

If you do not know the index of the required variable, then use this -

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] == required:
        break

element_1 = mylist[i]
```

Or - `element_1 = mylist.pop(mylist.index(required))`

Then you can access that variable like -

```
print(element_1) # one
```

Answer (score 4):

use the pop method as follows

```
a = ['one','two','three']
b = a.pop(0)    #  removes the first element and sets b to 'one'
b = a.pop()     #  removes the last element and sets b to 'three'
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a good solution, but remember that `.pop` changes the original list.

Comment: In that case, we can use list indexing

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy.

```
# Create an array
arr = [0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]

# Use this if you know the index or the position of the element

my_variable = arr.pop(1) # Assigns 1 to my_variable

# If you dont know the index but the element that you want to remove

my_variable = arr.pop(arr.index(5)) # Assigns 5 to my_variable
```